# Handling error in ajax request in Select2

Tags: jquery-select2-4

I need to detect if user session is gone when expanding Select2 combobox. When that condition occurs, response is redirected to login page.

The Select2 is populated using an ajax call, so I have added this to the "ajax" parameter:

```
        transport: function (params, success, failure) {
                var $request = $.ajax(params);

                $request.then(success);
                $request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                });

                return $request;
            }
```

The problem is that the error reported is not in XHR format (in order to detect 401 HTTP code) but an error telling "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input".

When seeing the response using Chrome developer tools, I do see that the response was in XHR format with 401 HTTP code but Select2 transforms it in some way.

Is there a way to solve this?

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 2):

```
   ajax: {
    // ...
    error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
        console.log(error + ": " + jqXHR.responseText);
        return { results: [] }; // Return dataset to load after error
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers and post a short explanation why your code works.